# Is it possible to display this data horizontally in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012

I have a table that that is being joined by another table that looks like this:

```
Id    Score    Total
1      10       30
1      7        30
1      13       30
2      14       27
2      10       27
2      3        27
```

I want to be able to display this data like this in SSRS:

```
Id    1    2    3    Total
1     10   7    13    30
2     14   10   3     27
```

Can this be done and how?

Comment: Yes, look up adding a column group to a SSRS report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using a matrix.

You can add a row identifier for each id in your dataset (assuming you can modify the dataset, as you joined 2 tables). Below code is for SQL Server (T-SQL).

```
Select Id, Score, row_number() over (partition by id order by score) ident
from table
```

Output:

```
Id    Score    Ident
1      10       1
1      7        2
1      13       3
2      14       1
2      10       2
2      3        3
```

No need of the Total field, you can add it in matrix (`Right Click on ColumnGroup>Add Total>After`).

Use the above query in Matrix as shown below.

[image]