# SSRS 2012 Dynamic Column Number

Tags: reporting-services

I got a request from the client when using SSRS reporting Service. I am kind of new to the SSRS. hope that someone can help me out with the problem below.

I use a common example to show the problem.

In SSRS dataset1, the data is like follows

```
StuId           StuSubject  
--------------------------------
 1                "Math"
 1                "Geography"
 2                "Science"
 3                "Math"
 3                "History"
 3                "Music"
```

In the SSRS dataset2, the data is like this one

```
StuId          StuName    
------------------------ 
  1            "Tom"
  2            "Joseph"
  3            "Linda"
```

In the SSRS DataSet3 , it would be like

```
StuId             StuInt
--------------------------
 1                "Swim"
 2                "Chess"
 2                "Swim"
 2                "Running"
 3                "Game"
```

What i want in the SSRS report would be like this one

StuId  StuName  StuSubject  StuSubject  StuSubject  StuInt  StuInt  StuInt

---

1    "Tom"    "Math"   "Geography"   NULL  "Swim"   NULL     NULL

2    "Joseph" "Science"  NULL        NULL     "Chess" "Swim" "Running"

3    "Linda"  "Math"   "History"    "Music"   "Game"  NULL   NULL

The tricky part is that I don't know what is the maximum number of StuSubject for all these students, or more precisely, I don't like to set the limit of the 'StuSubject' columns because there could be hundred columns in the real case. I have thought of LookupSet function, but seems using LookupSet, you can only join multiple StuSubjects values with "," in one cell.

Any advice / suggestion would be much appreciated and thanks in advance

Edit : I could use Matrix control for one "join" situation, but is this possible to "join" multiple datasets into one finale one ?

Comment: What is the purpose of joining using SSRS functions? You're trying to solve the issue with a tool that is not intended to solve such kind of issues.  I'm not saying that this is impossible (although I'm not sure), I just want to point that better way is to solve this issue using appropriate tool.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for you is to use Matrix report item - it allows to perform data grouping by rows and columns. Your data, returned from DB, should be aggregate of those two datasets that you have - it should be set of rows in format (StuId, StuName, StuSubject).
You can then add row grouping by StuId (and child row grouping by StuName, but this is not necessary), and add column grouping by StuSubject. Details cell will simply output StuSubject.

[image]

Notice that although Lookup* functions allow you to do join data while processing the report, they are run while processing report by SSRS and thus are certainly less efficient (from my experience expressions almost always have really bad impact on report performance). Also, doing join whikle processing report is not a canonical way to develop the report, and not the best way to use SSRS engine, which works good when you need simple grouping or do not need grouping at all. The best approach is to generate SQL result as much close to what you want to display, as it is possible, taking into account context of report and common sense of course.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:

Use your `DataSet1` in your matrix as suggested approach from [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092362/is-it-possible-to-display-this-data-horizontally-in-ssrs/40093698#40093698).

Your query would be similar to below:

```
 Select StuId,StuSubject
'StuSubject' + Cast(row_number() over (partition by id order by score) as INT) StuSubjectVal
 from table
```

You should get the result like below (after using matrix).

```
StuId     StuSubject1     StuSubject2     StuSubject3......
```

Add a column to your matrix, and use the Lookup from DataSet1 to DataSet2.

```
=Lookup(Fields!StuId.Value, Fields!StuId.Value, Fields!StuName.Value, "DataSet2")
```

Have not tested it, but it should work.

Comment: that would work if only use StuSubject dataset, what if there are one more dataset to join based on the StuId key, then how should I do that.

Comment: Use lookup as mentioned in lower part of my answer to join multiple datasets.